# Frames missing when exporting plot to PDF in 11.1.0

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format, mac-os-x, eps-format

I get the following result when exporting this plot:

```
g = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Export["~/Desktop/g.pdf", g]
(* "~/Desktop/g.pdf" *)
```

[image]

The frames are missing from the exported plot.

I see this problem in Mathematica 11.1.0 on OS X, with the PDF and EPS format. I do not see it with raster formats (like PNG).  I do not see it 11.0.1.

```
$Version
(* "11.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 16, 2017)" *)
```

- Can anyone else reproduce this?  How about other platforms than Mac?
- What exactly triggers the problem?  I do not see the problem with `g = Graphics[{Circle[]}, Frame -> True]`
- Is there a simple workaround for the problem?

Comment: No problem with version 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64. Have you tried other PDF viewer?

Comment: Please upload somewhere the exported PDF file for comparison.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Temporarily available here: http://ge.tt/3usZtNj2